# 'Specified cast is not valid' when I reload listview items - Xamarin Forms

Tags: forms, listview, xamarin, exception, binding

I'm trying to make an app that saves subjects into an SQLite database and I'm facing an exception: 'Specified cast is not valid'. That happens when I reload the listview items.
(SubjectViewModel.UpdateSubjects())

I receive the data from SubjectServices static class, with async connection.

I set the contentpage binding context to this viewmodel and then set the listview itemssource's binding the SubjectViewModel's SubjectList.

XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resources"
             x:Class="MyApp.View.ShellPages.SubjectsPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="{x:Static resx:AppResources.NewSubject}"
                     Command="{Binding SubjectNewSCommand}"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="subjectListView" ItemsSource="{Binding SubjectList}"
                  IsRefreshing="True" RefreshCommand="{Binding SubjectRefreshCommand}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding AddedTime, StringFormat='{0:d}'}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

SubjectViewModel:

```
using MyApp.Model;
using MyApp.View.ShellPages;
using MyApp.ViewModel.Commands;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;

namespace MyApp.ViewModel
{
    public class SubjectViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Subject> SubjectList { get; set; }
        public SubjectPageRefreshCommand SubjectRefreshCommand { get; set; }
        public SubjectNewSubjectCommand SubjectNewSCommand { get; set; }
        public SubjectViewModel()
        {
            SubjectRefreshCommand = new SubjectPageRefreshCommand(this);
            SubjectNewSCommand = new SubjectNewSubjectCommand(this);
            SubjectList = new ObservableCollection<Subject>();
        }

        public async void UpdateSubjects()
        {
            var subjectList = await SubjectServices.GetSubjects();
            SubjectList.Clear();
            foreach (var subject in subjectList)
                SubjectList.Add(subject);
        }

        public async void Navigate()
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new NewSubjectPage());
        }
    }
}
```

Subject class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;

namespace MyApp.Model
{
    public class Subject
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime AddedTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What could be the problem? I've tried to find any solution but didn't succeed.
I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: seems like your code is perfect, but the data(AddedTime) you are getting from GetSubjects() is not proper.

Comment: Which line of UpdateSubjects() method throws exception. For debug purpose add try catch and see from what to what typecast is failing.

Comment: the exception object contains a stack trace that should tell you which specific line causes the exception, or you can step through it using the debugger to determine.